# cURL vs MIME: POSTing a file

Tags: api, http, curl, post, content-type

## Question

I have written a very simple API using Flask, and I would like to upload a file to it using a POST command. I can easily make it work using cURL, but not so much using a logic app.

I have been using the [Mozilla MIME Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) trying to construct the HTTP call, but I am not sure what to use in the header and body.

What I know is:

- I would like to be able to send any file type, so I think I have to use the following:

  - Content-Type: application/octet-stream
  - Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.xxx"
- I have my file encoded with Base64, so I need to write that somehow, and place it in the body
- I would like to use chunking. Does this make any difference?

## My API

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def print_hello():

        if request.files:
                request.files['file'].save("/home/ebbemonster/cool_file.txt")
                return "Hello World"
        return "Goodbye World"

if __name__=="__main__":
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

## cURL

```
curl -X POST 13.81.62.87:5000 -F file=@GH019654.MP4
```

## Logic App

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out how to convert a cURL POST to a HTTP header/body.

## Fetching header/body details

```
# Logging post call
curl -X POST XX.XX.XX.XX:5000 -F file=@GH019654.MP4 --trace-ascii post.log

# Fetching header
head -n 30 post.log

=> Send header, 216 bytes (0xd8)
0000: POST / HTTP/1.1
0011: Host: XX.XX.XX.XX:5000
0029: User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
0042: Accept: */*
004f: Content-Length: 300745456
006a: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------
00aa: ----ec1aab65fb2d68fd
00c0: Expect: 100-continue

# Fetching body
sed -n '18,25p' post.log

0000: --------------------------ec1aab65fb2d68fd
002c: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="GH019654.
006c: MP4"
0072: Content-Type: application/octet-stream
009a:
009c: ....ftypmp41 ...mp41....mdatGPRO@...HD7.01.01.70.00LAJ9022436601
00dc: 517...................................1...US.8'.f..C328132710684
011c: 1.HERO7 Black........................E.....1...US.8'.f..........

# Fetching end of body
tail -n 30 google.log

02c2: --------------------------ec1aab65fb2d68fd--
== Info: HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
```

## Logic App Header/Body

[image]